# create an DOM inspector by c#?

Tags: c#, html

is there any library to create a DOM Inspector like firebug using c#? i need to fetch Xpath of a web page element by click and use them for extract value of this element by code.

it may be useful if there be a tool like chrome or firebug that extract that element as a config file or have an API to use in programming language like javascript or C#.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) and for `js` veriosn you can also take a look at: https://github.com/janmyler/DOM-inspector

You can Also check [anglesharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/)

Comment: I test agility pack but i want a visually interface which user can select elements and retrieve XPath of it by click

Comment: Dom-Inspector is ok but i wand to select element by clicking on main content and highlight dom tree. not clicking on dom tree and highlight body.